# An internal error occurred during: "Syncing to CLI...". java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: error-handling, device, appcelerator, genymotion, appcelerator-studio

When i configure the geymotion with appcelerator studio and click acept show that error An internal error occurred during: "Syncing to CLI...". java.lang.NullPointerException. I can't play the device of genymotion. I have a win 8 x64 and amd procesor

Comment: It looks like you've found a bug. Stack Overflow is [not the right place](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company) to report bugs. I've opened a ticket at https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TISTUD-8026. Please watch it to be informed about the progress.

Comment: In the meanwhile, downgrading to a Genymotion version < 2.6.0 will likely solve the issue for now.